# Layouts overlapping in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, layout, next.js

I am new to Next.js and I have a problem.
I created layouts, Header and Footer, as is said in the documentation. But, layouts are overlapping. What I mean is that the queue is not Header, main, and Footer. Part of the main content is inside either Header or Footer as you show in the image.

[image]

Here is my Layout component:

```
<>
      <Header />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
```

And here is my _app.js:

```
<Layout>
     <Component {...pageProps} />
</Layout>
```

Also, i added height: 100vh and width: 100% into globals.css
How can i fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `position: fixed` in any of your components' CSS? That could cause this issue.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for helping! Also, how I can make the footer at the bottom of the page? I could not figure it out in next.js.